# Ipython Notebook - ImportError: tornado

Tags: ipython, tornado

I have already updated tornado using

**sudo pip install --upgrade tornado**

Checking the current version show that I already have a version later than 4.0

Find the output of command:

**pip show tornado | grep Version**

```
Metadata-Version: 1.1
Version: 4.1
```

Any idea why Ipython notebook does not work and keeps giving me the message that i do not have  tornado v4.1 and have version 3.0 instead ?. Thanks and Regards.

=========================================================================
$ipython notebook

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/ipython", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(start_ipython())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/IPython/__init__.py", line 120, in start_ipython
    return launch_new_instance(argv=argv, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/IPython/config/application.py", line 573, in launch_instance
    app.initialize(argv)
  File "<string>", line 2, in initialize
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/IPython/config/application.py", line 75, in catch_config_error
    return method(app, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/IPython/terminal/ipapp.py", line 321, in initialize
    super(TerminalIPythonApp, self).initialize(argv)
  File "<string>", line 2, in initialize
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/IPython/config/application.py", line 75, in catch_config_error
    return method(app, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/IPython/core/application.py", line 369, in initialize
    self.parse_command_line(argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/IPython/terminal/ipapp.py", line 316, in parse_command_line
    return super(TerminalIPythonApp, self).parse_command_line(argv)
  File "<string>", line 2, in parse_command_line
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/IPython/config/application.py", line 75, in catch_config_error
    return method(app, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/IPython/config/application.py", line 471, in parse_command_line
    return self.initialize_subcommand(subc, subargv)
  File "<string>", line 2, in initialize_subcommand
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/IPython/config/application.py", line 75, in catch_config_error
    return method(app, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/IPython/config/application.py", line 402, in initialize_subcommand
    subapp = import_item(subapp)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/IPython/utils/importstring.py", line 42, in import_item
    module = __import__(package, fromlist=[obj])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/IPython/html/notebookapp.py", line 50, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg + ", but you have %s" % tornado.version)
ImportError: The IPython Notebook requires tornado >= 4.0, but you have 3.2
```

Comment: There are probably different copies of pip installed in different places, and it's not finding the right one. Try repeatedly doing `pip uninstall tornado` until it can't find any more copies. Then see if you can still import it, and if so, where it's coming from.

Answer (score 7):

I had a conflicting copy of tornado (3.1.1 on ubuntu 14.04) as well.  To see if this is the case for you, in a terminal use the commands:

`apt-cache policy python-tornado`

To print out the OS's version.  If it is not the version you want, use:

`sudo apt-get remove python-tornado`

to remove it.  If you had already installed the newer version using `pip`, that version will be visible to python now.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe have many pip and many Python's. Check your pip version

```
pip --version
```

(my response) pip 1.5.4 from /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (python 2.7)

and check you IPython environment:

```
~$ ipython3
Python 3.4.0 (default, Apr 11 2014, 13:05:11) 
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

IPython 1.2.1 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.
```

If environ version are the same. Try make new environ on virtualenv

Answer (score 0):

I have noticed that there were two Tornado packages installed on my system(Ubuntu 14.04). A Tornado 4.1 version and Tornado 3.2 version under different folders. In order to solve the problem, i renamed the folder containing the old Tornado to "Tornado-OLD".
Now Ipython Notebook is able to find the right Tornado and open on the browser.

I am not sure how it happened to have 2 versions of Torando installed, at the same time. But if you have the problem, this can probably help you.

Thanks for the contributions.
Regards
Gustavo

Comment: This seems hacky but honestly it's the only think that worked for me, so far.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try:

```
sudo apt-get remove tornado
sudo pip uninstall tornado
sudo pip install tornado
```

Answer (score 0):

The following worked for me:

Remove tornado:

```
sudo apt-get remove python-tornado
```

Reinstall tornado:

```
sudo pip install tornado
```

Upgrade tornado:

```
sudo pip install tornado --upgrade
```